# Select query from to Date using c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Simply i want to get query result in specific date (From - To)
I used this code

```
conn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Territories , ProductName , Forecast as ForecastVol , ForecastVal , Volume as Acheived , Value , Percentage as TotalIndex , Date from  TotalInSales where Territories = '" + TerritoryCB.Text + "' and ProductName = '" + ProductCB.Text + "' and Date " + "between @p1 AND @p2" + "  ", conn);
SqlParameter fromdate = new SqlParameter("@p1", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
fromdate.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
SqlParameter todate = new SqlParameter("@p2", SqlDbType.NVarChar);


todate.Value = dateTimePicker2.Value;
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(fromdate);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(todate);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
TotGrid.DataSource = dt;
SqlCommand sumvol = new SqlCommand("select sum(Volume) from TotalInSales where Territories = '" + TerritoryCB.Text + "' and ProductName = '" + ProductCB.Text + "' and Date " + "between @p1 AND @p2" + " ", conn);
AchVol.Text = sumvol.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
SqlCommand sumval = new SqlCommand("select sum(Value) from TotalInSales where Territories = '" + TerritoryCB.Text + "' and ProductName = '" + ProductCB.Text + "' and Date " + "between @p1 AND @p2" + " ", conn);
AchVal.Text = sumval.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
SqlCommand TotalValcom = new SqlCommand("select sum(ForecastVal) from TotalInSales where Territories = '" + TerritoryCB.Text + "' and ProductName = '" + ProductCB.Text + "' and Date " + "between @p1 AND @p2" + " ", conn);
TotalVal.Text = TotalValcom.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
SqlCommand TotalVolcom = new SqlCommand("select sum(Forecast) from TotalInSales where Territories = '" + TerritoryCB.Text + "' and ProductName = '" + ProductCB.Text + "' and Date " + "between @p1 AND @p2" + " ", conn);
TotalVol.Text = TotalValcom.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
SqlCommand Percentagecom = new SqlCommand("select(sum(Value) * 100) / (ForecastVal)from TotalInSales  where Territories = '" + TerritoryCB.Text + "' and ProductName = '" + ProductCB.Text + "' and Date " + "between @p1 AND @p2" + "  group by ForecastVal", conn);
Percentage.Text = Percentagecom.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
conn.Close();
```

I want to get this query between date selected in `dateTimePicker1` and `dateTimePicker2`

Date datatype is `date`

but it get me error in

```
AchVol.Text = sumvol.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

The error message

```
Must declare the scalar variable "@p1".
```

what's the solution

Comment: You have 6 different queries there. Which specific one do you mean? Also - why only two parameters? What you have with the SQL concatenation is very open to SQL injection - you really should be using parameters for those too.

Comment: i want 6 queries included date from to

Comment: If your two text fields have a single quote (apostrophe) in them this all breaks.  Please use parameters for those as @DigiFriend suggests.

Comment: date like 5-21-2017 .. didn't have apostrophe

Comment: Amr : Don't need apostrophe.  Apostrophe converts object to a string and if database field is set to DateTime then apostrophe is wrong.

Comment: There are two errors.  1) If the database has the date defined as a DateTime then the parameter type should be DateTime (not varchar). 2) The Parameter has to be added to each command.  You just have a parameter without the command.

Comment: I fixed the 2 errors but didn't work .. it got "The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection."

Comment: Sigh. Sql injection issues rear their ugly head once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created a **new** command (you do that 5 times):

```
SqlCommand sumvol = new SqlCommand("select sum(Volume) from TotalInSales where Territories = '" + TerritoryCB.Text + "' and ProductName = '" + ProductCB.Text + "' and Date " + "between @p1 AND @p2" + " ", conn);
```

These commands do not have any parameters attached to them - you have only ever attached them to your data adapter, not the commands.

For example:

```
sumvol.Parameters.Add(fromdate);
sumvol.Parameters.Add(todate);
```

You should also convert all the string concatenation you are doing and use proper parameters for them too - you have opened yourself to [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) with this concatenation.

Comment: @MuratSEKERMCT - nope. Only to the data adapter. Read the code.

Comment: @AmrKamal - yes. They don't know about the parameters if you don't add them.

Comment: The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection.
get this error

Comment: @DigiFriend you are right. and it could be better to define your parameter names like fromDate - toDate instead of p1

Comment: @AmrKamal - you need to add them to **the new commands**, not to the data adapter again.

Comment: Digi i did .. like this 
SqlCommand sumvol = new SqlCommand("select sum(Volume) from TotalInSales where Territories = '" + TerritoryCB.Text + "' and ProductName = '" + ProductCB.Text + "' and Date " + "between @p1 AND @p2" + " ", conn);
                    sumvol.Parameters.Add(fromdate);
                    sumvol.Parameters.Add(todate);
                    AchVol.Text = sumvol.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
is that wrong ?

Comment: That *should* work, @AmrKamal - but you need to do the same with all commands.

Comment: i did but got this error
The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection

Comment: If you are adding them all to the same command, you would get that error. You are creating new commands all the time - need to add to them. To debug stuff - start by simplifying (do just one command till you get it working, then add another one till you get *that* working etc...).

Comment: works only with dataadapter and got me the same error in one command

Comment: @AmrKamal - what I have been saying is exactly what CodingYoshi has been in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a parameter for your from date and to date for each and every command that needs it. So if you have n number of commands then you need to create them for all n commands. So create the following for each command and add it to this the command's `Parameters` collection.

```
SqlParameter fromdate = new SqlParameter("@p1", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
fromdate.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
SqlParameter todate = new SqlParameter("@p2", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
todate.Value = dateTimePicker2.Value;
```

If you try to use the above for multiple commands, it will not work and you will get this exception because they cannot be shared between multiple commands:

> The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection.

Comment: That's right i got the same error .. then no solution for multiple commands ?

Comment: You need to create the above for each command. If you have 5 commands, you need to create the above 5 times. Get it?

Comment: u mean must declare a new parameter each time ?